# Concatenated DATEVALUE() and TIMEVALUE() only returns string in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Good morning everyone, currently losing my marbles over this and hoping there's a workaround. I concatenated two values to jerry-rig a timestamp, and converted a string into a number conditionally:
`TIMEVALUE(IF(H2="Breakfast","08:00:00",0))+DATEVALUE(C2)`

I then formatted this into a timestamp in Google Sheets, and used `IMPORTRANGE()=` to use in another sheet. BUT, when I plugged the values into `MAX()`, it always returns `DATEVALUE(0)`, "12/30/1899 00:00:00". I wanted to sort and get the most recent date, but these values refuse to sort. Some notes:

1. Everything is in datevalue format;
2. I've tried a workaround using `SORT()`, which didn't work (it just returned the unsorted range);
3. Currently using this as a workaround: `RIGHT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER('Sheet1'!C1:DU1,'Sheet1'!C2:DU2=1)))`, but this is causing issues because I can't use `SORT()`.

4. I am using a lot of helper sheets and imported ranges (I did read that this can cause problems, but it's not clear on if those are fixable issues.)
5. This formula does return the values I'm asking for; I just want it to sort, which I know I can't do with string values.

I'm probably missing something huge. Please help!

Sorry—here's a link to a dummy version of the Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NmdEgnDU0fHTeRWpagrr1niORnlfwZO8uYCkSYrfFLA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: try this formula to find max value _=query(IMPORTRANGE("-SheetID-";"-SheetName!Range-");"select Max(Col1) where Col1 is not null label Max(Col1)''";)_ where your timeshtamps are in the first column of imported range

Comment: @RafaGuillermo added a dummy version, let me know if there's any issues with the link

Comment: @kmck339 can you make the dummmy sheet copiable?